# Using Flask session variables in sqlalchemy models

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model that has a field as `lastModifiedById`. I want it to automatically populate itself with the is of the user currently logged in. This is available in `flask.session['personId']`.

The following give me an `out of request context` error:

```
lastModifiedById = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"), default=session['personId'], onupdate=session['personId')
```

If I replace the above with the following:

```
def get_session_person_id(): 
    if has_request_context():
        return session['personId']
     else
        return None


lastModifiedById = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"), default=get_session_person_id(), onupdate=get_session_person_id())
```

It seems that when application boots up the `get_session_person_id` method is called multiple times but when I update my SQLAlchemy model it is not called.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a simple typo:

```
 lastModifiedById = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"), default=get_session_person_id, onupdate=get_session_person_id)
```

Notice how the parentheses were removed from function names.